# error when compiling the source code for cesium

Tags: node.js, git, npm, cesiumjs

I wanted to set up a cesium in windows 7. When I set up the cesium and download the relevant software, i received errors. So I will explain to you on how I set up and install and where I got the error from.

I download  and install the git from this website, https://git-scm.com/download/win.

I download and install node.js from this website,
https://nodejs.org/en/

I git clone this website, git clone https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium.git in git bash

Once it is done, i npm install from node command prompt I got this error which states 
"

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules\fse
vents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}
```

"
I research for this error and they states that this is a warning so I continue doing the next steps.

I made changes to the cesium source code, C:\cesium\Source\Widgets\Animation\AnimationViewModel.js 
I made a modification in this code

```
AnimationViewModel.defaultDateFormatter = function(date, viewModel) {

    //var gregorianDate = JulianDate.toGregorianDate(date);

    var isoDate = Cesium.JulianDate.toIso8601(date);

    var localDate = new Date(isoDate);

    return monthNames[localDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + localDate.getDate() + ' ' + localDate.getFullYear();

};



AnimationViewModel.defaultTimeFormatter = function(date, viewModel) {

    //var gregorianDate = JulianDate.toGregorianDate(date);

    //var millisecond = Math.round(gregorianDate.millisecond);

    var isoDate = Cesium.JulianDate.toIso8601(date);

    var localDate = new Date(isoDate);

    if (Math.abs(viewModel._clockViewModel.multiplier) < 1) {

        return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d', localDate.getHours(), localDate.getMinutes(), localDate.getSeconds(), localDate.getMilliseconds());

    }

    return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d SGT', localDate.getHours(), localDate.getMinutes(), localDate.getSeconds());

};
```

Then i run the npm run release i got this error from the below..

```
C:\cesium>npm run release

> cesium@1.38.0 release C:\cesium
> gulp release

[17:22:32] Using gulpfile C:\cesium\gulpfile.js
[17:22:32] Starting 'build'...
[17:22:33] Finished 'build' after 930 ms
[17:22:33] Starting 'generateStubs'...
[17:22:33] Finished 'generateStubs' after 142 ms
[17:22:33] Starting 'combine'...
Building Cesium.js
[17:22:33] Starting 'minifyRelease'...
Building Cesium.js
[17:22:33] Starting 'generateDocumentation'...
Building Source/Workers/cesiumWorkerBootstrapper.js
Building Source/Workers/transferTypedArrayTest.js
Building Source/Workers/cesiumWorkerBootstrapper.js
Building Source/Workers/transferTypedArrayTest.js
Finished Source/Workers/transferTypedArrayTest.js
Building Source/ThirdParty/Workers/inflate.js
Finished Source/Workers/transferTypedArrayTest.js
Building Source/ThirdParty/Workers/inflate.js
Finished Source/Workers/cesiumWorkerBootstrapper.js
Building Source/ThirdParty/Workers/deflate.js
Finished Source/Workers/cesiumWorkerBootstrapper.js
Building Source/ThirdParty/Workers/deflate.js
Finished Source/ThirdParty/Workers/inflate.js
Finished Source/ThirdParty/Workers/deflate.js
Building Source/Workers/combineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createBoxGeometry.js
Finished Source/ThirdParty/Workers/inflate.js
Finished Source/ThirdParty/Workers/deflate.js
Building Source/Workers/combineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createBoxGeometry.js
Finished Cesium.js
Finished Source/Workers/createBoxGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/upsampleQuantizedTerrainMesh.js
Finished Source/Workers/combineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/transcodeCRNToDXT.js
Finished Source/Workers/combineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/upsampleQuantizedTerrainMesh.js
Finished Source/Workers/createBoxGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/transcodeCRNToDXT.js
Finished Source/Workers/upsampleQuantizedTerrainMesh.js
Building Source/Workers/decodeGoogleEarthEnterprisePacket.js
Finished Source/Workers/transcodeCRNToDXT.js
Building Source/Workers/createWallOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/upsampleQuantizedTerrainMesh.js
Building Source/Workers/decodeGoogleEarthEnterprisePacket.js
Finished Source/Workers/transcodeCRNToDXT.js
Building Source/Workers/createWallOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createWallOutlineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createWallGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/decodeGoogleEarthEnterprisePacket.js
Building Source/Workers/createVerticesFromQuantizedTerrainMesh.js
Finished Source/Workers/decodeGoogleEarthEnterprisePacket.js
Building Source/Workers/createWallGeometry.js

[17:24:12] Finished 'generateDocumentation' after 1.63 min
Finished Cesium.js
Finished Source/Workers/createWallGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createVerticesFromHeightmap.js
Finished Source/Workers/createWallOutlineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createVerticesFromQuantizedTerrainMesh.js
Finished Source/Workers/createVerticesFromQuantizedTerrainMesh.js
Building Source/Workers/createVerticesFromGoogleEarthEnterpriseBuffer.js
Finished Source/Workers/createVerticesFromHeightmap.js
Building Source/Workers/createSphereOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createVerticesFromGoogleEarthEnterpriseBuffer.js
Building Source/Workers/createSphereGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createWallGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createVerticesFromHeightmap.js
Finished Source/Workers/createVerticesFromQuantizedTerrainMesh.js
Building Source/Workers/createVerticesFromGoogleEarthEnterpriseBuffer.js
Finished Source/Workers/createSphereOutlineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createSimplePolylineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createSphereGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createRectangleOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createVerticesFromHeightmap.js
Building Source/Workers/createSphereOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createSimplePolylineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createRectangleGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createRectangleOutlineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createPolylineVolumeOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createVerticesFromGoogleEarthEnterpriseBuffer.js
Building Source/Workers/createSphereGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createRectangleGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createPolylineVolumeGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createPolylineVolumeOutlineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createPolylineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createSphereOutlineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createSimplePolylineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createPolylineVolumeGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createPolygonOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createSphereGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createRectangleOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createPolylineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createPolygonGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createSimplePolylineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createRectangleGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createPolygonOutlineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createPolygonGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createFrustumOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createRectangleOutlineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createPolylineVolumeOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createFrustumGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createFrustumOutlineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createEllipsoidOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createRectangleGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createPolylineVolumeGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createFrustumGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createEllipsoidGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createEllipsoidOutlineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createEllipseOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createPolylineVolumeOutlineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createPolylineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createEllipsoidGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createEllipseGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createEllipseOutlineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createCylinderOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createPolylineVolumeGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createPolygonOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createPolylineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createPolygonGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createCylinderOutlineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createCylinderGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createEllipseGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createCorridorOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createCylinderGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createCorridorGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createCorridorOutlineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createCircleOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createPolygonOutlineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createPolygonGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createFrustumOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createCorridorGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createCircleGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createCircleOutlineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createBoxOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createFrustumGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createBoxOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createCircleGeometry.js
[17:26:03] Finished 'combine' after 3.48 min
Finished Source/Workers/createFrustumOutlineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createEllipsoidOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createFrustumGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createEllipsoidGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createEllipsoidOutlineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createEllipseOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createEllipsoidGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createEllipseGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createEllipseOutlineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createCylinderOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createCylinderOutlineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createCylinderGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createEllipseGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createCorridorOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createCylinderGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createCorridorGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createCorridorOutlineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createCircleOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createCorridorGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createCircleGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createCircleOutlineGeometry.js
Building Source/Workers/createBoxOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createBoxOutlineGeometry.js
Finished Source/Workers/createCircleGeometry.js
Building Source/Widgets/Animation/Animation.css
Building Source/Widgets/Animation/lighter.css
Finished Source/Widgets/Animation/lighter.css
Building Source/Widgets/widgets.css
Error Source/Widgets/Animation/Animation.css
[17:26:49] 'minifyRelease' errored after 4.25 min
[17:26:49] Error: Command failed: npm run requirejs -- --eyJ3cmFwIjp0cnVlLCJ1c2V
TdHJpY3QiOnRydWUsIm9wdGltaXplQ3NzIjoic3RhbmRhcmQiLCJwcmFnbWFzIjp7ImRlYnVnIjp0cnV
lfSwiY3NzSW4iOiJTb3VyY2UvV2lkZ2V0cy9BbmltYXRpb24vQW5pbWF0aW9uLmNzcyIsIm91dCI6IkJ
1aWxkXFxDZXNpdW1cXFdpZGdldHNcXEFuaW1hdGlvblxcQW5pbWF0aW9uLmNzcyJ9 --silent
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cesium@1.38.0 requirejs: `gulp requirejs "--eyJ3cmFwIjp0cnVlLCJ1c2VTdHJ
pY3QiOnRydWUsIm9wdGltaXplQ3NzIjoic3RhbmRhcmQiLCJwcmFnbWFzIjp7ImRlYnVnIjp0cnVlfSw
iY3NzSW4iOiJTb3VyY2UvV2lkZ2V0cy9BbmltYXRpb24vQW5pbWF0aW9uLmNzcyIsIm91dCI6IkJ1aWx
kXFxDZXNpdW1cXFdpZGdldHNcXEFuaW1hdGlvblxcQW5pbWF0aW9uLmNzcyJ9" "--silent"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cesium@1.38.0 requirejs script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sgshaa11\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-10-17T09_26_
49_092Z-debug.log

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:271:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
Finished Source/Widgets/widgets.css
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cesium@1.38.0 release: `gulp release`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cesium@1.38.0 release script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sgshaa11\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-10-17T09_26_
51_831Z-debug.log
```

I also got the error when I npm install. it states

```
npm Error npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10
```

Mind explaining to me on how to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: Does it work without the code customizations?  Is there a different error then?  Also, for what you're trying to do here, you don't need to modify Cesium source code, there's a way to apply this change from outside of Cesium.

Comment: Couple of other notes: 1. You can't use the `Cesium.` prefix inside Cesium source code itself, 2. You hard-coded the `SGT` label, but your code will display time in the browser's local time zone, which is not SGT for my machine, and 3. You go through an ISO string to get to a JS Date, but I'm pretty sure there's a helper function to get you directly from JulianDate to JS Date.

Comment: last time i have tried to set up cesium and change the timezone it work but right now the cesium is corrupted and I have to reinstall

Comment: i got the error when i set up cesium